# What way should I choose instead multiply overloading?

Tags: java, oop

I've got public method1(...) in some not-final class, which widely used in our project.

But I need to add some if-condition in to internal last private method of this class and do not break other business logic, implemented previously: (we got nested methods)

```
public static method1(...) { 
  method2(...)
}

private static method2(...) { 
  method3(...)
}

private static method3(...) { 
  method4(...)
}

private static method4(...) { 
 // here I want to add some if-condition
}
```

Should I overload all methods in order to introduce some boolean flag through parameters list for switching to my special condition in some situations OR I can make a private field in the class and just put  it to my `private metod4(...){...}` ? Does in last way I get smelly code ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your class is not final, then you can create a subclass and override the last method.

Comment: I can't do this, because method1 is static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is your Project architecture and how much refactoring is acceptable, but my first idea was for [State](http://www.journaldev.com/1751/state-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) design pattern, because is a good choice when your object alter its behavior and its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class.

But here **actually is more about encapsulation**. Since all you *methods (M2,M3,M4) are private* there is no need to worry about

> not break other business logic implemented previously: (we got nested methods)

simply because they are not exposed to others. So as *bottom-line* - the changes are most likely to be proper if affect the *public* M1. Please note that chaining here is crucial in order to preserve the processing of the final result. The behavior of the method4 should be changed obviously. So the *overloading of the private methods* is a good option, if your suggested

> private field in the class

is calculated in the invocation tree and not passed as param somehow.

Maybe if you post some more info or code - the answers will be more helpful.

- Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Having many connected static methods (with plural parameters passed around) is non-optimal for maintenance.

1. The first naive measure would be to introduce a class for the parameter lists (every parameter becomes a field). Then the parameter class might be extended without the methods changing.
2. Better consider whether static methods may become normal methods, and the class partly statefull.

   ```
   public class C {

       protected final A a;
       protected final B b;
       protected X x;

       public C(A a, B b) { }

       public void setX(X x) { }

       public void method1() {
           method2();
       }
   ...
   ```

Or combine them.

One method calling the other in succession with the same parameters looks needing an Object Oriented rewrite.